# Error executing script GenerateController: No such property: f for class: SimpleTemplateScript1

Tags: variables, grails, groovy

ok, I wanted to save some time for all here, guess that was not the smartest way. so here i got with what i am doing. please go slow on me as I am just born in grails world. Let me know my approach is ok, or if there is a smarter way.

I have two tables  abc and  def. I want to move data from abc to def based on some rules.  For my project,  I am expecting several such cases in future (mapping tables klm with xyz, pqr with jkl so on so forth), hence the need for generalization).

The classes Abc and Def are shown below

```
class Abc {

String firstAbc
String secondAbc

static constraints = {
    firstAbc(nullable:true)
    secondAbc(nullable:true)
}
}

class Def {

String fieldA
String someRandomField

static constraints = {

}
}
```

I created a domain class called Mappings (that will act as parent for all future mappings) that is shown below

```
class Mappings {

String inputTable // in this case this will be abc
String inputField // can be firstAbc or secondAbc
String inputValue // some value

String outputTable // def in this case
String outputField // either of fieldA or someRandomField
String outputValue
}
```

Then I extended Mappings to create my specific instance called AbcDefMapping, that is shown below

```
class AbcDefMapping extends Mappings {
}
```

The rules for mapping abc with def are stored in AbcDefMapping. One such rule could be when abc.firstAbc is “jack”, store “jacky” in def.fieldA. The values for mappings in this case would be
    inputTable = abc
    inputField = firstAbc
    inputValue = “jack”
    outputTable = def
    outputField = fieldA
    outputValue = “jacky”

I want to add a method called transform() in Controller.groovy  that would do the needful, so that in future I just create the domain classes, mapping class and generate the controller. This is how my transform method looks like so far. But I cant get any further, till I resolve the issue at hand. If I resolve this issue, maybe I will get to next step. Struggling for past few days as you all know

```
def transform(){
    def csplit = []
    def count = 0
    for (i in ${className}){
        if (i == i.toUpperCase() && count!=0){
            csplit.add(count)

        }
        count++
    }
    def inputs = ${className.substring(0,3)}.list() // here instead of manually inserting 3, I need to insert csplit[0].length
    def inputTable = ${className}.substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + ${className}.substring(1,3) //replace 3 with csplit[0].length
    def mappings = ${className}.executeQuery(" from ${className} acm  where acm.inputTable = '" + inputTable + "'  order by acm.inputField, acm.inputValue, acm.outputField, acm.outputValue")
    println mappings


}
```

Comment: hmm what happens if you change it to def inputs = "${className.substring(0,f)}".list() ?

Comment: I get the above error "Error Error executing script GenerateController: No such property: f for class: SimpleTemplateScript1"

Answer (score 0):

The `Controller.groovy` template is effectively a giant string. That means anything in `${}` is evaluated and substituted into the string.

It's hard to guess what you're actually trying to do. What you have currently:

```
def f = 5
def inputs = ${className.substring(0,f)}.list()
```

is going to try to generate code that matches that, but there is no variable `f`, only a string that reads `def f = 5` which will end up in the generated controller. When you actually use the value `5`, the expression in the GString is able to be evaluated correctly.

Comment: Hi doelleri, thanks for your response. I am still getting the error.  I am using above code in a method in Controller.groovy and get the error on running generate-controller, if that helps.

Comment: Hi Doelleri, thanks for explaining the whole concept and your patience. However, it does not solve my problem. I am new to the whole Groovy / Grails world, so my questions / approach could be not the best. I simplified my question by defining a variable. actually f is generated way above in the code and would change from one controller to another, thus the use of variable. Is there any way I can make my code work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't tell you how to make your code work because I have no idea what it's supposed to be doing

Comment: I am creating a new method in Controller.groovy that uses this code. 

I played around a bit and am getting a new error. if i change 

    def inputs = ${className.substring(0,f)}.list() 

to 

    def inputs = ${className.substring(0,/f/)}.list()

I am now getting 
 Error Error executing script GenerateController: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.substring() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String) values: [0, f].

Comment: You still haven't explained your real problem or what you're trying to do. In that snippet you've just made `f` into a slashy string, and that's not going to change that you're doing it wrong.